# Implementing Java interfaces and methods

Tags: java, interface

I'm learning about Java interfaces and method writing. I'm wondering how you would create a class that uses this interface?
Also what are the best ways to implement the methods it includes? 
At the moment, i'm trying to learn different ways for writing methods.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
interface Dealer {

    void assignPlayers(ArrayList<Player> p);

    ...

    public void settleBets();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple:

```
public class BakratDealer implements Dealer {
    // implement all the methods here
}
```

It's not about the *best* way; this is the *only* way.  You must either implement all the methods in the interface or declare the class `abstract`.

The interface need not use the `public` keyword; all the methods in an interface are public by default.

Comment: and to add, all the variables delcared in the interface are constants. :)

Comment: public static final, to be precise.

Comment: which are deafult for constant .. :P

Answer (score 1):

use `implements` keyword in your class declartion to implement an interface

```
public class YourClass implements Dealer {

 //implement all your method defined in the interface here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the class the same way you inherit another class except you use the word "implements" instead of "extends".

Example -
public class TestClass implements Dealer {
     }

In the class that is using the implementation, you write the methods just as  you would write any other method. You just have to be sure to implement ALL the methods from the interface or the class has to be an abstract class.